# I want to recover and play again my lost village

Tags: clash-of-clans

I lost my village after the maintenance update. I want to play my previous village, this time, I am playing a new created village that replaced my previous one. Please help me back on my previous enjoyed village.

How can I play again my old village? I want to play again so bad. I hope you can help me return from playing by recovering my old village.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities :

Either you made an account on clash of clans which allowed you to save your data, just connect with that account and your village should be restored.

Either you didn't make one, and well, I'm sorry for you...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an Apple device, (IPhone, IPad, etc.), log into Game Centre with the Apple ID you used to download the game, your account should be saved on it.

Same thing with Google Play if you're on Android, log in with the account you used to download it and your progress should be saved on it.

Comment: I accidentally press community wiki *sigh*